# Rewriteconds won't work locally

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I setted up a local environament using vagrant and virtualBox,

And some of this rules I have in my `.htaccess`  (wich work in production code) will fire 404 error, when in production environament work perfectly

This one, for example works:

`# hostname/posts/?show=lasts -> posts.php?show=lasts`

`RewriteRule ^posts/$ posts.php?$1&friendly=1 [QSA]`

Won't work (404):

`# hostname/page/the-title/5 -> page.php?id=5`

`RewriteRule ^page/(.+)/(.+) page.php?id=$2&friendly=1`

Any idea what I'm missing?

hostname in production it's like `page.com` and in the virtual machine it's `localhost:8085` in case it helps

-EDIT-

Full block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%20(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1-%2 [L,R=301,NE]



ErrorDocument 500 /oohps.php
ErrorDocument 404 /where.php

RewriteBase /
# Quitar www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Canonicación de la IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^70.XX.XX.XXX [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^s158783.gridserver.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# URLS amigables
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)/(.+) page.php?id=$2&friendly=1 
RewriteRule ^pregunta/(.+)/(.+) pregunta.php?id=$2&friendly=1
RewriteRule ^new/(.+)/(.+) new.php?id=$2&friendly=1
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/(.+) user.php?que=user&id=$2&friendly=1 
RewriteRule ^pages-de-cocina/$ pages.php?$1&friendly=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)/(.+) pages.php?que=cat&f=$2&friendly=1 [QSA]
```

URL's that fail:

```
/page/the-title/4  
/user/the-name/6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)$ posts.php?$1&friendly=1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^page/[^/]+/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&friendly=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I tried but i had same result. 404. I had the rewrite engine/base you suggest preceding my code.. any idea? thanks!

Comment: Is this in document root's .htaccess? Which URL is causing 404? Are there any existing rules also? If yes please provide them in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, its in the document's root. Updated question, I believe first rewrite you helped me doing it already :P

Comment: You also need this line at the top of your .htaccess: ` Options -MultiViews` otherwise `mod_rewrite` doesn't work properly with content negotiation.

Comment: Yay! your last comment had my solution! thanks a lot!

Comment: Any thoughts on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422954/htaccess-filesmatch-only-if-host-name-matches ? :P